# how to return bool in void C#

Tags: c#

So I'm new to C# and I was messing around in creating my own "language" (basically it takes my language and converts it to C# then compiles) I was writing a function to check if something was in a string or not and I came across the error CS0127. I did a bit of surfing on the internet and could not find a solution that works. Here's my code.

```
void CheckQuote(string item, string line)
{
    if (!line.Contains(item))
    {
        // return false
    
    }
}
```

I am actively working on it, so things might have changed by the time you read this.

Comment: Void methods by definition have no return value. Why do you want this  method to be void?

Comment: Required reading: **[void (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/void)**.  Spoiler:  *`the method doesn't return a value`*  Additionally the online docs help for CS0127 says *`a void return type cannot return a value`*.  All the information is out there, you just have to let it in

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you want to 'return ' a bool from a function there are several ways

The obvious one is

```
bool CheckQuote(string item, string line)
{
    if (!line.Contains(item))
    {
         return false
    
    }
    return true;
}
```

used like this
if(!CheckQuote("a","b"))
// error case

if for some reason the method has to be void (why tho), you can do

```
void CheckQuote(string item, string line, out bool result)
{
    if (!line.Contains(item))
    {
        result = false
    
    } else{
       result = false;
}
```

then call it like this

```
 bool check;
 CheckQuote("a", "b", out check);
 if(!check)
    // error case
```

one way more convoluted way

```
 public class Checker{
      bool Result {get;set;}
      void CheckQuote(string item, string line)
      {
          if (!line.Contains(item))
          {
               Result = false;
           } else{
               Result = true;
           }
      }
  }
```

used like this

```
  Checker check = new Checker();
  check.CheckQuote("a","b");
  if(!check.Result)
      // error case
```

but thatsway over the top

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by storing the result in public static property and read its value after calling the "void" method for example:

```
public static class TestClass
{
    public static bool PublicProperty { get; set; }
}
```

so in your "void" method you need to store value like this:

```
void CheckQuote(string item, string line)
  {
    if (!line.Contains(item))
     {
       // return false
      TestClass.PublicProperty = false;
     }
  }
```

and after calling your "void" method you can read the property value like this :

```
var someVariable = TestClass.PublicProperty;
```

but this is not practical
don't use void but use it it as a boolean method

```
bool CheckQuote(string item, string line)
  {
    if (!line.Contains(item))
     {
       return false          
     }
     return true;
  }
```